# Huge Memory Leak UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios6, uiimagepickercontroller

I've seen other threads but mine seems to be even more dramatic. I am using UIImagePickerController to allow users to choose or take their own pictures.

Here's some code:

```
if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO))
        return NO;

    ImagePickingViewController *cameraUI = [ImagePickingViewController sharedImagePickingController];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;

    cameraUI.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:^{
        //do nothing
    }];
```

As soon as this executes, my memory allocations go from ~3MB to 6MB of active memory. And when I hit cancel to dismiss the view, the memory stays at 6MB!! If I choose an image, it goes even higher and many times crashes.

Any ideas?

I'm running iOS 6 and not using ARC.

[EDIT]: Here is code without my class wrapper. It does the exact same thing - leak 3MB memory when the view is displayed and never goes back down even after view is dismissed.

```
if (([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:
          UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == NO))
        return NO;

    UIImagePickerController *cameraUI = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    cameraUI.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    cameraUI.allowsEditing = NO;

    cameraUI.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:cameraUI animated:YES completion:^{
        //do nothing
    }];
```

And here are the delegate methods

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info{
    NSLog(@"Image picker finished picking.");
    [self.navigationController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        //do nothing
    }];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{
        //do nothing
    }];

    UIImage *originalImage = (UIImage *)[info objectForKey:
                                    UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
        //Do stuff with image
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker{
    [loadingViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
        //Do stuff
    }];
}
```

Comment: But there is no UIImagePickerController in this story, so why do you put the blame there? The question is, what is `ImagePickingViewController`? We have no way of knowing what this is. For all anyone knows, that's the class where the memory problems begin. Your code gives no reason to believe there's a problem with Apple's class UIImagePickerController, or that it's even involved.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. ImagePickingViewController is simply an empty wrapper on UIImagePickerController as a singleton. I see a 3MB memory jump when the view is pushed (using allocation/leak inspector) and it never goes back down. I also tried this directly allocating/releasing a UIImagePickerController and switched to the singleton due to comments on SO, but it did not solve the issue, thus my post.

Comment: UIImagePickerController is not a singleton. The rules for using it are clear. It is a view controller. You don't dispense a singleton view controller! It is managing a view. It needs to come into existence and go out of existence in good order. You instantiate it, present it, dismiss it, let it dealloc. Just use UIImagePickerController as it is intended. Otherwise it is YOU who is mismanaging memory.

Comment: Okay... Either way I stated it does the same thing no matter if it's a singleton or not. I have edited my post to show you the code. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: That's great but your new code makes no sense to me. In `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` are you dismissing two things? In `didCancel:` why are you *manually* messing with a view controller's view? There is a lot more going on here, and the "a lot more" is probably the source of your difficulties. I have two pieces of advice: (1) behave correctly and cleanly with regard to view controllers, and (2) if you think there are memory problems, don't guess - use Instruments to measure them and track them down.